# Insert a Wordpress contact form 7 in a custom template page

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I've been trying to insert a WP contact form 7 in a custom 'blank' page template.

Actually what I'm trying to do is insert the WP CF7 functionality in a very basic, clean page (just a nice background, able to adjust font, images, ...) but I don't want the page the look like this blogpost from the WP theme..

I've tried to upload a white page template with FTP, 
but when I try to embed to WPCF7 code in the new page with the blank template, nothing happens...

Anybody who can help me out?

Thanks a lot!

White page template

```
   <?php /* Template Name: Blank Page
*
* A blank custom page template.
*
* The "Template Name:" bit above allows this to be selectable
* from a dropdown menu on the edit page screen.
*
*/
?>


<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: u may `echo do_shortcode()` in the template

Comment: Why use `echo do_shortcode()` in the template?

Comment: @DhruvinMoradiya read above

Answer (score 0):

Write Your code Like this:

```
<?php
/* Template Name: Blank Page
*
* A blank custom page template.
*
* The "Template Name:" bit above allows this to be selectable
* from a dropdown menu on the edit page screen.
*
*/

get_header();

$id= get_the_ID(); 
$post = get_post($id); 
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); 
echo $content; 

get_footer();
```